# JIRA-REST-JAVA - Error MalformedInputException on creating issue

Tags: jira-rest-java-api

I'm using jira-rest-java-client-core and jira-rest-java-client-api (2.0.0-m31) wih maven.
GET an issue works fine but i've a problem when I try to create one.

```
JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
JiraRestClient jiraRestClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(URI.create("https://jira_host"), username, password);
IssueRestClient client = jiraRestClient.getIssueClient();
IssueInputBuilder issueBuilder = new IssueInputBuilder("TEST", 1L, "Summary Test");
IssueInput issueInput = issueBuilder.build();
BasicIssue issue = client.createIssue(issueInput).claim();
```

and the error :

```
org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.LoggingAsyncRequestExecutor exception
GRAVE: http-outgoing-1 [ACTIVE(5)] HTTP protocol exception: Input length = 1
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:277)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:193)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:171)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:171)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultHttpClientIODispatch.onInputReady(DefaultHttpClientIODispatch.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultHttpClientIODispatch.onInputReady(DefaultHttpClientIODispatch.java:50)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:342)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:320)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:604)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Have you got an idea to resolve that ?

Tks,
Alexander

Comment: I have the same error during version _creation_ (on any project) ... Finally on every `POST` (issue, version, ...). _update_ operations done with `PUT`, without errors. I try using _httpcore-nio_ v4.2.5, same problem (and v4.4 not compliant with JIRA HTTP Client).

Comment: Bug [JRJC-191](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/JRJC-191) created.